# how to use php call linux GPG encrypt file with a passphase

Tags: php, gnupg

I have a task which need to

**use gpg to encrypt the upload file in php**

my code is:

```
("echo '1234' | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -c /path/aaa.jpg ");
```

it works by paste the code in linux

but not work by php any solution

Comment: How have you tried to use that in PHP? Simply as written?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [gnupg_decypt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-decrypt.php) to decrypt the text.

Comment: im asking encypt while upload, is that any solution

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at the manpage for that module.  It gives you an interface to do gpg stuff from php.

Comment: but it said "string gnupg_encrypt  ( resource $identifier  , string $plaintext  )" plaintext?

Comment: @user "Plaintext" as opposed to "cipher (encrypted) text".